# Checking if any character in a string is alphanumeric

Tags: python, string, alphanumeric

I want to check if any character in a string is alphanumeric. I wrote the following code for that and it's working fine:

```
s = input()

temp = any(i.isalnum() for i in s)
print(temp)
```

The question I have is the below code, how is it different from the above code:

```
for i in s:
    if any(i.isalnum()):
        print(True)
```

The for-loop iteration is still happening in the first code so why isn't it throwing an error?  The second code throws:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 18, in 
>     TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: The `any` statement has a different scope in your two functions. In the second case you apply `any` to a single element.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your second function you apply `any` to a single element and not to the whole list. Thus, you get a single bool element if character `i` is alphanumeric.

In the second case you cannot really use `any` as you work with single elements. Instead you could write:

```
for i in s:
    if i.isalnum():
        print(True)
        break
```

Which will be more similar to your first case.

Comment: Oh gotcha. So I got lost between working with single elements and the entire list as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`any()` expects an iterable.  This would be sufficient:

```
isalnum = False
for i in s:
    if i.isalnum():
        isalnum = True
        break
print(isalnum)
```